# Turn string into object - But to actual text, not evaluated

Tags: r

Don't think this is a duplicate, as I want the actual code/text, not evaluated.

I am building a function that requires the inputs to be like the following:

```
compss[[1]](x[1],x[2])
```

Where compss is a list of functions, and I am calling the first function in the list, and using the parameters x[1] and x[2].

**The Question**

I want to build a general case such that when I have more than 2 variables, i get:

```
compss[[1]](x[1],x[2],x[3],.....)
```

(As in, I type n = 5, and I get the actual code above, but up to x[5])

**My failed approach**

So my initial thought is to first create a vector with n "x[i]'s",

```
argss <- NULL
  for (i in 1:length(variable.limits)){
    argss <- c(argss, text = paste("x","[", i, "]", sep =""))
  }
```

Which gives:

```
"x[1]" "x[2]" ....
```

Then I thought using parse would help, but this gives:

```
expression(x[1], x[2])
```

Which would be fine and I could use do.call etc...
But the problem is that I just want the symbols/objects/variables there. The reason is I am running this into a optimisation function, where x[1] does not have a set value, and so do.call seems to fail. Any ideas?

**Comments response**

In response to the comments, r2evans solution of using:

```
list_of_xs <- list(x[1], x[2], x[3])
do.call(compss[[1]], list_of_xs)
```

Is probably the best way to solve this, so now the only question left is how to generalise the "list_of_xs".

My use case is designing a cost function for a non-linear programming:

```
func <- function(x){
x[1]*x[2]*x[3] + (x[1]^2 - x[3]*x[2])
}
```

But I am trying to design this within my framework, so it works for general problems, where we may have up to say x[100]. 
The package I am using, namely "nloptr", requires you to input the cost function in a certain form, I think, I am new to this package.

Comment: Would it be easier to use something like `do.call(compss[[1]], list_of_xs)` instead of building it textually? (`list_of_xs` might be as simple as `list(x[1], x[2], x[3])`, built programmatically.)

Comment: This is a nice fix, and does work, but to make this generalised to n variables, I need to generate the list_of_xs, with the same contents you listed, but for n. Should I change the question to be more specific about how now the remaining question is to generalise the list?

Comment: Too vague at the moment. Provide an example of some  functions you want to see illustrated and the corresponding  `x`'s you might expect.

Comment: @42- I agree, I have added the use case, hope this helps, thank you.

Comment: So you are hoping for generality within the body of the function, and not in the arguments list? Why wouldn't that example be solved by using `prod(x)`

Comment: @42- Yes exactly, I have changed the example to show my question better. Sorry it wasn't clear. (The actual cost function is more complicated)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create the character representation in `txt` and then use `parse` on that.  Use [[1]] on the parsed object to return a `call` object which I am assuming is what you want.

```
n <- 3
txt <- sprintf("compss[[1]](%s)", toString(paste0("x[", 1:n, "]")))
cobj <- parse(text = txt)[[1]]
cobj
## compss[[1]](x[1], x[2], x[3])

# check that we can evaluate cobj
compss <- list(function(a, b, c) a + b + c)
x <- 1:3
eval(cobj)
## [1] 6
```